# iOS App in AppStore crashes after update to iOS 8.0.2 but still running on devices and simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash-reports

i got the problem with the App published in AppStore for a long time ago. The problem did appeared after update to iOS 8.0.2 and it seems to crash only on devices with iOS 8.0.2 by selecting UITableViewCell and pushing another UITableView. When a run the app in Simulator (iphone 6 with iOS 8.0) or on device (iphone 5s with iOS 8.0.2) i got no crashes!

Development with: Xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317) and Simulator Version 8.0 (550.1)

This crash log i get from iphone 5s (myAppName and myCompanyName are placeholder):

```
Incident Identifier: 08332336-8EB8-46FE-A2EF-ABD2CE09881E
CrashReporter Key:   7ada6e35d37d8707ba1d6998b81491a622418c8e
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:             myAppName [2629]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9C0AFA6C-8C2C-4A44-9DAA-27ABF1326EA1/myAppName.app/myAppName
Identifier:          myCompanyName
Version:             3.0
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-10-08 17:40:14.116 +0200
Launch Time:         2014-10-08 17:40:12.799 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 8.0.2 (12A405)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x24076e3f __exceptionPreprocess + 127
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31752c8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                  0x23f94ec3 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 850
3   myAppName                       0x00043e23 0x3000 + 265763
4   myAppName                       0x00043b3f 0x3000 + 265023
5   myAppName                       0x00044339 0x3000 + 267065
6   UIKit                           0x2761d1af __66-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]_block_invoke + 514
7   UIKit                           0x275e2bb3 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 4018
8   UIKit                           0x275e1b41 -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 328
9   UIKit                           0x275e1981 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 56
10  UIKit                           0x275e17b9 -[UITableView _updateContentSize] + 344
11  UIKit                           0x275e7503 -[UITableView didMoveToWindow] + 70
12  UIKit                           0x27511ff5 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1312
13  UIKit                           0x27530da3 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 50
14  UIKit                           0x27511d65 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 656
15  UIKit                           0x27511d65 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 656
16  UIKit                           0x27511671 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 112
17  UIKit                           0x2751158d -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 428
18  UIKit                           0x2751b9b3 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1434
19  UIKit                           0x2751b413 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 30
20  UIKit                           0x275c74bf -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 478
21  UIKit                           0x275c72db -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:toView:] + 26
22  UIKit                           0x275beb67 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2286
23  UIKit                           0x275bdff3 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 578
24  UIKit                           0x2759b1f7 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 1506
25  UIKit                           0x27807ba9 __54-[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:]_block_invoke + 356
26  UIKit                           0x2759ac03 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 494
27  myAppName                       0x00006ea1 0x3000 + 16033
28  UIKit                           0x2762b477 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 918
29  UIKit                           0x276dcd7f -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 194
30  UIKit                           0x2758ed0d _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 308
31  UIKit                           0x2750ac4b _afterCACommitHandler + 458
32  CoreFoundation                  0x2403d5cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
33  CoreFoundation                  0x2403ac8b __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 278
34  CoreFoundation                  0x2403b093 __CFRunLoopRun + 914
35  CoreFoundation                  0x23f89621 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
36  CoreFoundation                  0x23f89433 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
37  GraphicsServices                0x2b2f80a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
38  UIKit                           0x27574359 UIApplicationMain + 1440
39  myAppName                       0x00004df9 0x3000 + 7673
40  myAppName                       0x00004d0c 0x3000 + 7436


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31d98dfc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31e16d33 pthread_kill + 59
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31d38905 abort + 73
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x310779c5 abort_message + 85
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3109166d default_terminate_handler() + 265
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31752f23 _objc_terminate() + 191
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3108ede1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 77
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3108e8ab __cxa_rethrow + 99
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31752dcf objc_exception_rethrow + 39
9   CoreFoundation                  0x23f896b9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 629
10  CoreFoundation                  0x23f8942f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
11  GraphicsServices                0x2b2f80a5 GSEventRunModal + 133
12  UIKit                           0x27574355 UIApplicationMain + 1437
13  myCompany                       0x00004df5 0x3000 + 7669
14  myCompany                       0x00004d08 0x3000 + 7432

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000003
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x341bf9dc      r6: 0x341ab840      r7: 0x001803f8
    r8: 0x1764f6a0    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x341aa074     r11: 0x1764f6c4
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x001803ec      lr: 0x31e16d37      pc: 0x31d98dfc
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

I think the problem can be on libraries which were updated with new iOS 8.0.2 or something like this.

I urgently need help to fix this issue!

Comment: can you symbolicate the crash? Line 3 to line 5 are important to fix the problem.

Comment: do you mean that's lines:  3   `code` libc++abi.dylib                 0x310779c5 abort_message + 85
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3109166d default_terminate_handler() + 265
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31752f23 _objc_terminate() + 191 `code`

Comment: No. In thread 0 there are some lines which start with "myAppName" . Those are the lines of code from your app which are causing the crash.

Comment: as I already said, there is an AppName and hexcode behind

Comment: @AlexejW. You need to symbolicate your crash report otherwise you can't determine which line of code the crash is occurring on

Comment: @AlexejW. please read this : http://kevincupp.com/2011/05/12/symbolicating-ios-crash-logs.html

Comment: thanks AkaMu i will take a look at this! how can i do it ;) I do not have much experience with it...

Comment: when i symbolicate the mentioned code i will post it so fast if i can!Thank you for help!!!

Comment: @AkaMu I tried to make symbolicate yesterday. What I have tried: 1. symbolicate with Xcode right click on .crash on iphone 5s re-symbolicate (without success)

Comment: 2. Terminal: getting files myApp.app and myApp.dSYM from release build (.xcarchive) and myApp.crash with command:`code` DEVELOPER_DIR=`xcode-select -print-path`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -o ./myApp-resymbolicated.crash ./myApp.crash ./myApp.app.dSYM `code` RESULT: Without changes in re-symbolicate.crash!

Comment: I guess: 1.I have wrong build settings ([link] (http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems)) for TARGET or/and PROJECT so that it was not possible to symbolicate 2.The UUID's in myApp.dSYM and myApp.app are equals, BUT in myApp.crash different 3. issue is somewhere else in some new lib..(iOS 8.0.2)4.But the main thing is, the app runs today (yesterday were the app published in Appstore and directly downloaded and testet by me with the crash) without to reproduce the crash.WTF???Thank's @all for the help and information about symbolicate!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure its the same issue, but I also seeing some crashes coming from 8.0.2 and it has something to do with fonts.

For example I have this customization in my AppDelegate:

```
    [[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:14.0]];
```

Which lead to those crashes.

Comment: Even i'm facing some crashes in 8.0 and 8.0.2.We also do font customizations as you mentioned.Is there an issue with fonts in 8.0 and 8.0.2 ?

Comment: seems so, only solution so far is to remove the font customization for those iOS versions.